# A series of books about a teenager that went to the moon to fight mould

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, moon

I read a series of books, probably around 1962 - 1970, about some young kid (a teenager) whose name I think was Chris.

There was a problem with the Moon, it was being invaded by a mould (mold) which was some sort of threat to the Earth.

For some reason, only a single person could go in a spacecraft to deal with this threat, and Chris was chosen.

He had a few mentors, there was a friendly one, and a "harsh" one, who Chris thought hated him.

In one of the books, his rocket ship became disabled, and one of the adults had to fly up to save him. He naturally thought it would be the "friendly mentor" but it turned out to be the "harsh mentor" who actually had a high regard for Chris, but couldn't let on, because that would endanger the mission or something.

I think it was set in England.

In one of the books Chris was heading towards the space training centre, when he was set upon by some "Teddy Boys" who forced him to lick their shoes (or something similar). One of his mentors came upon this scene and was initially disturbed that Chris was a coward, but he revealed that being beaten up just before flying to the moon would have not helped the mission.

Does anyone recognise these?

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154929/60s-70s-story-about-english-people-chris-et-al-going-to-mars-and-hibernating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [*Chris Godfrey of U.N.E.X.A.* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/153078-chris-godfrey-of-u-n-e-x-a) by [Hugh Walters](http://unexa.org/walters/). The mould actually shows up in *[Expedition Venus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12115299-expedition-venus)*; A space probe returns to Earth from Venus, and lets loose a mould which quickly spreads. Chris and his friends have to journey to Venus to find an antidote.

"Chris Godfrey of U.N.E.X.A."

1. *Blast Off at Woomera* (1957)
        aka *Blast Off at 0300*
2. *The Domes of Pico* (1958)
        aka *Menace from the Moon*
3. *Operation Columbus* (1959)
        aka *First on the Moon*
4. *Moon Base One* (1961)
        aka *Outpost on the Moon*
5. *Expedition Venus* (1962)
6. *Destination Mars* (1963)
7. *Terror by Satellite* (1964)
8. *Journey to Jupiter* (1965)
9. *Mission to Mercury* (1965)
10. *Spaceship to Saturn* (1967)
11. *The Mohole Mystery* (1968)
         aka *The Mohole Menace*
12. *Nearly Neptune* (1968)
         aka *Neptune One is Missing*
13. *First Contact?* (1971)
14. *Passage to Pluto* (1973)
15. *Tony Hale, Space Detective* (1973)
16. *Murder on Mars* (1975)
17. *The Caves of Drach* (1977)
18. *The Last Disaster* (1978)
19. *The Blue Aura* (1979)
20. *The Dark Triangle* (1981)

Boy Astronaut

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm impressed. As you can imagine, without remembering the author, title, or publisher, it was hard to have a starting point for finding a book I remember from my school days. It gives me confidence to ask about another book. But that's for another question. :)

Comment: One book I was considering asking an identity question about involved a trip to the moon with a boy in the crew, and mysterious, sinister mists rolling along the Lunar surface.  A comment in another question led me to the Chris Godfrey series, and a synopsis showed that one of the books in the series was the one I remembered.